# Relay fetchQuery does not work after history.push BUT works fine in manual refresh

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I'm developing a react-relay-graphql app with authenticaton and I want to show new messages count in `Header` component (navigation).
Here is `Login` Component code:

```
...

LoginMutation(username, password)
            .then((resp) => {
                if (resp.token) {
                    this._saveUserData(resp.expiredAt, resp.token)
                    fetchQuery(environment, query, {})
                        .then(data => {
                            const me = data.user.me;
                            this.setState({
                                Auth: {
                                    user: {
                                        fullName: me.fullName,
                                        username: me.username,
                                        isSeniorUser: me.isSeniorUser
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            this.props.setUser(this.state.Auth.user)  // Redux
                            this.props.history.replace('/dashboard')
                        });
                }
            })

_saveUserData = (expiredAt, token) => {
    localStorage.setItem(GC_USER_EXPIRES_AT, expiredAt)
    localStorage.setItem(GC_AUTH_TOKEN, token)
}

...
```

And here is `Header` Component (It is inside `Dashboard` Component)

```
class Header extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getMessagesCount()
    }

    getMessagesCount() {
        fetchQuery(environment, NewMessagesQuery, {})
            .then(data => {
                const newMessagesCount = data.message != null ? data.message.countNewMessages.newMessages : '';
                this.props.setNewMessagesCount(newMessagesCount) // Redux
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.props.newMessages}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

**The problem is** after `History.push` it shows dashboard BUT `fetchQuery` does not even run and it returns `data = {messages: null}`, but when page manually refreshes, It works and new messages count is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
In case anyone came to this problem, My cache Config in `Environment.js` was wrong. So it was trying to read data from cache for each request.